# Is it valid to "dllexport" a C++ class when all functions are defined in the header?

Tags: c++, v8, dllexport

Here's a class from the Google V8 Javascript engine. It's `dllexport`, but all of the functions are fully defined in the header file. **Is it valid to `dllexport` a class in C++ when all of the functions are defined in the header?** I imagine that the class would not get defined in any compilation unit, and would not end up getting exported from the DLL.

It might make a difference that this particular class is a *nested* class within another class, `v8::Isolate`.

My platforms, in case it is relevant to the answer, are Windows 10/MSVC++2017 and Ubuntu 18.04/GCC.

```
  /**
   * Stack-allocated class which sets the isolate for all operations
   * executed within a local scope.
   */
  class V8_EXPORT Scope {
   public:
    explicit Scope(Isolate* isolate) : isolate_(isolate) {
      isolate->Enter();
    }

    ~Scope() { isolate_->Exit(); }

    // Prevent copying of Scope objects.
    Scope(const Scope&) = delete;
    Scope& operator=(const Scope&) = delete;

   private:
    Isolate* const isolate_;
  };
```

Comment: Its valid, those exported functions just won't ever get used since the linker doesn't need them.  Unless the class has virtual functions, then you'll use the exported v-table.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I follow you. Because the definitions are in the header, the linker won't need to look in the DLL at all for the symbols, it'll be compiled in directly to the the library that is importing the exported class.